# CSS highlight menu item based on page body tags

Tags: css

I have a menu, I would like to highlight the sub menu item based on the page they are in. Can I use a div tag with an id on the page, and in css if the id is there then highlight the item.

in body

```
<div id="doc3"></div>
```

then in css

```
#doc3 #menu li#subnav-5-1 a
```

I tried this but dosent seem to work. How can I change the style of another element based on id in the page body?

menu...

```
<!-- Menu 5 -->     
    <li id="nav-5"><a href="ssslate.do">Micro</a>
      <ul id="subnav-5">
          <li class="subnav-5-1"><a href="asdf.do">Site & Visit</a></li>
          <li><a href="ss.do">MIC</a></li>
          <li><a href="ss.do">sss</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

CSS

```
body.nav-5-1 li.subnav-5-1 {background-color:red;}
```

htmlbody

```
<body id=nav-5-body class="nav-5-1">
```

Thanks

Comment: Try removing all the dashes from your class names.  Different browsers behave differently with dashes in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a class on each item in the menu and then use sub-classing in your CSS to highlight the item based on the body.

So the body would have a class that defined the page:

```
<body class="userEdit">
```

And the menu items would have classes on them that were the same:

```
<li class="userView">
<li class="userEdit">
<li class="userAdd">
```

Then your CSS would look like:

```
body.userEdit li.userEdit {background-color:red;} /* selected colors go here */
```

**However, this is an inefficient way to build a menu with a selected item**.  It would be better to simply determine which item is selected on the server and add a `selected` class to that item and then have `.selected {background-color:red;}` in your CSS.  This would save bits and scale better.

Comment: I tired, updated the post... did not work did i do something wrong..?

Comment: Try removing all the dashes from your class names.  Different browsers behave differently with dashes in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown us your actual html structure.
The css style you have specified (`#doc3 #menu li#subnav-5-1 a`) will affect a html structure like this:

```
<div id="doc3">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li id="subnav-5-1"><a href="somePage.html">Some page</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The style will be applied to the `<a>` tag.